# How to use x64 assembly with C++ on windows?

Tags: c++, assembly, g++, mingw, nasm

cpp.cpp:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

extern "C" int returnnum();

int main() { std::cout << returnnum() << "\n"; }
```

asm.asm:

```
segment .text
global _returnnum
_returnnum:
    mov rax, 420
    ret
```

First, I compile the assembly file with `nasm -f win64 asm.asm`.

Then, I compile the C++ file with `g++ cpp.cpp asm.obj`.

But this gives me an error:

```
asm.obj: file not recognized: File format not recognized
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I know that I can change `rax` to `eax` and compile with `-f win32` and it'll work, but I want a 64-bit application. Is there any way I can do this?

If this is helpful:

`g++ --version`: g++ (MinGW.org GCC-6.3.0-1) 6.3.0
`nasm --version`: NASM version 2.15rc12 compiled on Jun 26 2020

Comment: I think it would be helpful to add the exact compiler version and distribution you used.

Comment: Are you sure your `g++` is a 64 bit build tool, rather than 32 bit? Wondering if it might be defaulting to compiling your `.cpp` in 32 bit mode and getting confused by the use of a 64 bit object file.

Comment: compile the cpp.cpp first and then only link the object files

Comment: @ShadowRanger How do I check that? Adding `-m64` throws ```cpp.cpp:1:0: sorry, unimplemented: 64-bit mode not compiled in
 #include <iostream>```

Comment: @PawełŁukasik `ld` throws `asm.obj: file not recognized: File format not recognized`

Comment: I'd use https://jmeubank.github.io/tdm-gcc/ . Download the one on the left that is mingw-w64 based. It has a 64-bit tool chain.

Comment: @avighnac: Sounds like you got your answer; your `g++` doesn't implement 64 bit targets. Guessing you installed MinGW not MinGW-W64?

Comment: You may want to use msys2 and install mingw64 with gcc-11.3: [https://www.msys2.org/#installation](https://www.msys2.org/#installation) also [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30069830/how-to-install-mingw-w64-and-msys2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30069830/how-to-install-mingw-w64-and-msys2)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on your information from the comments and your `g++ --version` output, it looks like you installed plain [MinGW](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MinGW) (which is purely 32 bit, and works just fine if you only need to build 32 bit executables since Windows supports running 32 bit executables on a 64 bit OS) rather than [MinGW-W64](https://www.mingw-w64.org), the fork with native support for 64 bit Windows.

You'll need to switch if you want to build true 64 bit executables.